# web page looking weird in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

please have a look at this web page [Click Here](http://www.articlesnmore.in)

The page looks fine in IE or Chrome but gives very wierd output in firefox.

I am not very good with designing and not able to figure out what is wrong here because view source is same for both the browsers than y firefox is giving strange output.

EDIT

When i open it in IE or Chrome its fine but in firefox its gives lots of vertical spacing

Comment: ask better questions. specifically, what is "wierd" abotu it? how is it different in IE than in other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `TD` with `height="100%"`

remove the `height="100%"` from this line: `<td width="100%" valign="top" height="100%">`

Comment: Also, check your HTML tags, since the W3C validator says your page does not meet the standards: <http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.articlesnmore.in%2FArticles-subcatid-0-pageId-1.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0>. Basically, since you're using XHTML, you should use "&amp;" instead of "&", close standalone tags (e.g. use "<br />", not just "<br>") and nest some elements correctly. This is vital in ensuring your page will look the same on all browsers.